# publish biztalk service in seperate biztalk server Error

Tags: biztalk

I am New to biztalk

I have created two way port and publish my biztalk project as a biztalk service in my local machine.
Then I have Created Small Client App and access the Biztalk app through published biztalk  service. Successfully send the schema and received the response. But For same Application I have created an another web service in seperate server, which has biztalk.

I want the biztalk application in my local machine as it is , and access that biztalk application from seperate server biztalk service.

When I consumed the seperate server web service and try to call the web method, it says:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Internal SOAP Processing Failure
```

My Soap Transport Properties page web asmx:

```
/SampleBiztalkApp_Proxy/WebService_SampleBiztalkApp.asmx
```

My Soap Transport Properties page Public Address:

```
{RemoteMechineName}/SampleBiztalkApp_ProxyGID /SampleBiztalkApp_SampleOrchestration_PortRR.asmx
```

Is there any other configuration to do so?
If you have any idea about publishing biztalk service in seperate machine.
Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BizTalk Server has to be installed and configured on the other machine as well.  This is because the Receive Location is running in an Isolated Host within IIS but it's still BizTalk.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,
Biztalk Server installed and configured the other machine as well, But My biztalk application on My local server, Is there any place to bind hosted web service on separate machine with my local biztalk application ?

Comment: Couple of queries for clarification.
1. Is the remote server also part of the same BizTalk Group
2. How are you hosting the remote web service? Are you using the WCF Web service publishing Wizard?

Comment: Both machines have to be in the same BizTalk Server Group, so when you setup the second, you should have Joined the existing Group.  That way, they share the same MessageBox and any message received by the Isolated Host (IIS) can be picked up by Orchestrations or Send Ports on the other.  This is all done through the MessageBox.